# Locking translation axis for multiple objects

Tags: transforms

Selecting multiple objects and pushing lock button in properties panel "transformation" locks the axis only for one object in the selection of objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select all your objects, lock the channel, then right click on one of the lock icons and "copy to selected" to copy the locked status to the other objects.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thats it! So easy knowing how to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can apply the same "lock" to multiple objects by copying contraints from one object to others, but you have to "lock" your reference object with constraints (look the constraints tab in the selected object panels- right side of the default view) as in the image below.

Since the last selected object is the "active" object, you can get what you wish in this way: apply desired locks to one of the objects. Then select all the others, and as last *also* the locked one.

Then use the "copy constraint to selected objects" (use the space bar to find the command, or look under the menu "object > constraints").

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatly the copy of constraints has no effect on the selected objects. Also locking a parent object does not lock the children.

Comment: well, works here... are you sure to follow exactly the selection order? 
can you post the .blend?

Comment: Sorry you said about transform panel but I meant "constraint" so I rephrase my answer. Contraints will work, transform panel will not.

Comment: Constraints are a powerfool tool for complex tasks. Thanks for the advice.